# A factory produces 10 items. In how many ways can these items be categorized into 3 quality levels?

Tags: combinatorics

If the items are indistinguishable will the problem follow the model of dividing $10$ objects into $3$ bins, where the solution is $n+m-1$ choose $n$ so $12$ choose $10$? Or will this be more like a password problem where the solution is $3^{10}$?

What happens if it is required that there be at least $1$ object in each category?

Comment: you have asked four questions, ask one, analyse it, try similar approaches in the subsequent questions, if you can't ask another question. Also you should post what have you tried, and what you came upwith

Comment: @Shobhit: Siddharth has asked only two questions. One is essentially whether the title problem is a stars-and-bars problem or a simple application of the multiplication principle, and the other is how the problem changes if we require at least one object in each category. The first question already exhibits some effort on Siddharth’s part: the only two halfway reasonable problem types to which this one might belong have been identified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to make it clear if the 10 objects are undistinguishable then it's just a simple stars and bars problem, while if the 10 objects are different the total number of ways is $3^{10}$ as you mentioned.

If the 10 objects are undistinguishable, then to categorize them in 3 ways we use the stars and bars formula:

$$\binom{n+k-1}{k} = \binom{3+10-1}{10} = \binom{12}{10} = 66$$

The stars and bars problem is actually finding a number of distinct ways to make $n$-tuples, such their sum is $k$, where are number are non-negative integers.

If we want to restrict them only on positive integers then the formula is:

$$\binom{k-1}{n-1} = \binom{10-1}{3-1} =\binom{9}{2} = 36$$

So there are 36 distinct ways, such that every category has at least on item.

To find out more about the principle this formula works, look at the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29), you have a very nice exlpanation.

Comment: Thanks Stefan that makes a lot of sense. The trouble I had was with determining if the objects are distinguishable or not cause of ambiguity. In regards to the second part though, is there only 1 way to distribute 3 items across 3 categories such that there's 1 in each leading to 1*36?

Comment: There are 36 different ways to distribute them into 3 categories and each categorie having at least. You can do them all using stars and bars to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

The classic [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) approach here is the approach to use indeed (using approach $2$, theorem 2 in the link):

In this case, the task is equivalent to counting the number of ***non-zero*** integer solutions to the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 10$, where $k = 10$, $n = 3$ bins. in this case:  $$\binom{n + k - 1}{k} = \binom{10 + 3 - 1}{10} = \binom {12}{10}$$

In the second case, we can use theorem one from the same problem type of the "stars and bars" sort: the count is equivalent to the number of ***positive*** integer solutions (so no bin can be empty) to in this case $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 10$, where $k=10$ objects and $n = 3$ bins: $$\binom{k - 1}{n - 1}\binom{10 - 1}{3-1} = \binom{9}{2}$$